# Using Magento Framework as a dependency in module.xml

Tags: magento2, module, search, catalogsearch, plugin

Currently I am working on a plugin that modifies the Search in Magento 2
The file that I am trying to intercept is located at:
`\Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder`
To be able to use my plugin I need to add the "framework" folder inside my `module.xml` but I do not know **if** I can even include it

Already tried:

```
<module name="Magento_Framework" />  
<module name="Framework" />
<module name="framework" />
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtendedQuickSearch\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match;

class QuickSearch
{
    public function beforeGetMatchQuery(
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Helper\Mysql\Fulltext $subject,
        $columns, $expression, $mode = self::FULLTEXT_MODE_NATURAL
    )
    {
        var_dump('Plugin1 - beforeGetMatchQuery');die;
    }
}
```

That is my Plugin to intercept the "getMatchQuery()" public method.
I thought the only way it is not working because I could not declare the Framework as a dependency.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 3):

**You don't need to.**

Every single Magento module ultimately depend on the Magento framework because ... they are Magento modules.

On top of that, the Magento Framework is a library and not a module so it cannot be declared as a module dependency.